# Dotted edges in GraphPlot/GraphPlot3D

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, graph-theory

I'm trying to visualize some graphs and am looking for alternate ways to style the edges. I'm not entirely sure if changing the edge style would improve the representation, but even so I'm curious.

For example:

```
GraphPlot3D[{2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> Dotted, 
]
```

Doesn't work. Something like `EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Cylinder[#1, 0.05] &),` doesn't work well at all because the number of edges I am working with makes this incredible slow and doesn't look as good as the default line anyway.

Is there a way to systematically see what options Mathematica will accept? Any suggestions as to

Comment: How big is your graph? I ask because with 2000 edges the Cylinder function performs quite well in a poor's man laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systematic way is look through the list of options in Help. In `GraphPlot3D`'s help, in `PlotStyle` section, there are examples how to make dotted edges.

Additionally, if you do `GraphPlot3D[{2 -> 3}]//FullForm` you will see that edges are drawn with `Line` primitive, so look in `Line` help pages under `PlotStyle` for more supported properties. So for instance, `PlotStyle->Thick` works for `GraphPlot3D` even though it's not mentioned on GraphPlot3D's help page.

If you want to see undocumented options, you could do `Options[GraphPlot3D]`, `Information[GraphPlot3D]`, and if you really want to dig into undocumented stuff, look at Simon's comment in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091728/tips-for-creating-graph-diagrams)

Answer (score 1):

One example:

```
GraphPlot3D[{2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Dotted, Thick, 
     Arrowheads[{0.00, .03}], Arrow[#1, .05]} &)]
```

I'm not sure if this is the type of edge modification you want.